# Second order markov tranision probability matrix

Tags: r, markov-process, transition-matrix

I tried to find the second order Markov chain of the following sequence

Dat= A A B A B A A A B B A A B

I tried it on "Markov chain" package in R.

```
D=c("A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B")
fitHigherOrder(D,2)
```

I got this result

```
 $Q[[2]]
     A    B
A   0.3333333  0.75
B   0.6666667  0.25
```

But from [Fit and evaluate a second order transition matrix (Markov Process) in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147164/fit-and-evaluate-a-second-order-transition-matrix-markov-process-in-r) discussion, I am little bit confused. Suppose, if I want to calculate AA-B, from the following formula for 2nd order,

```
Tijk= Nijk/Nij
```

If I follow this formula, I got probability 1.0 for AA to B transition, as there are three times AA is followed by B and three times AA transition occurs.
If I am right, then how to interpret the "Markov chain" package result? I mean what is the correct way to show/ calculate the 2nd order Markov chain?

Comment: Which part of the referenced thread are you following?  The two answers given there are completely different and contradict each other.  Could you explain what you understand a "second order" Markov chain to be?

Comment: To me the second answer is reliable. To my understanding, first-order Markov chain is that follows just only the previous state. But in case of second-order Markov chain, it will follow previous two states. So, for 2nd order Markov chain, the transition probability should be n^2 x n dimension. If I am wrong, please enlighten me.

Comment: That is right.  Why, then, are you reporting a $2\times 2$ matrix?  This obviously is not the transition matrix.  For its meaning, please read the documentation for this `R` package.